# WYSIWYG without the HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, text, wysiwyg

Is it possible to take only the text from WYSIWYG editor? For example, if you have the following text:

```
<a href="whatever"> sdadsa<>,.<> <p </a>
```

is it possible to take only the text inside the `sdadsa<>,.<>`?

Some might say don't use the editor but i need it to make two copies one with the tags and the other without HTML tags and only HTML tags that they match.

Is it possible to take the text without the HTML tags?

Comment: You mean, you want to get the style, but without the HTML tags?

Comment: No i want to get the Text without the HTML tags. plain text

Comment: This is tagged with javascript; is jQuery an option? If so, the text() method should do what you're after. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip all HTML tags out of the output, you have two methods:

- **With PHP** - use `strip_tags($output)`.
- **With Javascript** - type

  `var plaintext= editorOutput.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");`

  or use [php.js's equivalent](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535) to the PHP method.

Comment: This strip_tags() has a problem i am retrieving -&gt or n&lt do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user1445117 your editor makes special characters for HTML. If you can tell me what editor you're using - that will be great.